# Add mutiple values to Django Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have the following model structure:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer_text

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    choices = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='choices')
    answer = models.OneToOneField(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

I have registered both the models on admin. But when I try to add multiple choices to a question in the admin, it does list any other answers.

[image]
See the attached screenshot. I am unable to add multiple choices for a question. When I  click the green + button, it does not list all possible answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your foreign key is the wrong way round. The model the field is defined on is the "many" side of the one-to-many relationship.

For a question that has multiple answers, the FK should live on Answer pointing to Question.

You can then use the "inlines" feature of the admin to define multiple answers on the same page as the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Is Question one side and Answer is on the many side?

Comment: Well if you want multiple answers for a single question, then yes. The point is, move the ForeignKey field to the Answer model.

Comment: I want multiple answers for a single question. So always, the foreign key is defined on many-side? Or how do I determine that?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are still confused about this. An FK points to a single item, so lives on the many side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this case [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). This allows you to bind multiple choices to different questions at the same time:

```
choices = models.ManyToManyField(Answer, related_name='choices')
```